# Icefaces Actionlistener Pass Parameter To Another Page

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, icefaces

I have have icefaces datatable and when user clicks a row, I would like to pass that row's value to another page. The value could row's one column which is the primary key. I am planning to use

How can I do this?

Thanks

****Follow up*****

Kindly suggest the approach I am following is the right for passing paramter from my icefaces 
datatable to another page.

I have the following in jsf page

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{bean.setSelectedItem}">
```

And in my bean of setSelectedItem(ActionEvent event) method I have the following code

```
 selectedRows.put(dataTable.getRowIndex(), true);  
 (selectedRows is of Map<Integer, Boolean> selectedRows = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
 List<class> selectItems = new ArrayList<class>();
             for (int index = 0; index < dataList.size(); index++) {                
                if (isSelectedRow(index)) {
                    selectItems.add(dataList.get(index));
                }
            }
            newbean.method(selectItems);
            selectItems.clear();
            selectedRows.clear();
```

Correct me if I am doing anthing wrong above.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either bind the table component with `UIData` property in backing bean

```
<h:dataTable binding="#{bean.table}">
```

with

```
private UIData table;
```

or bind the table value with `DataModel` property in backing bean

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.model}">
```

with

```
private DataModel model;
```

Either way, they offer a `getRowData()` method which gives you the row back during bean action method where the `UICommand` component is been clicked/pressed.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.view}">
```

with

```
public String view() {
    Object rowData = table.getRowData(); // Or model.getRowData();
    return "otherpage";
}
```